# Remainder Notification in Full Calendar

Tags: jquery, notifications, fullcalendar

I tried to implement remainder notification in Full Calendar(jQuery plugin) 
For eg : If I have an meeting at 06:00 PM , i should be notified 15 or 20 mins prior to the meeting .

Here is my code,

```
 setInterval(function(){ 
            var month=['january','february','march','april','may','june','july','august','september','october','november','december'];
            var date = new Date();
            $('.remainder').html("");
            var headerDate = $('.fc-center').text().split(' '); 
            if(headerDate[0].toLowerCase() == month[date.getMonth()] && headerDate[1] == date.getFullYear()){
                console.log(1);
               var allEvents = $('.fc-day-grid-event');
                $.each(allEvents,function(key,value){
                    var eventTime = $(value).find('.fc-time').text();   
                    if(eventTime.length !=0){
                    var getAmPm = eventTime.split('');
                    var AmPm = getAmPm[getAmPm.length-1];
                    var eventTimeArr = eventTime.split(':');
                    var eventDateIndex = $(value).closest('td').index();
                    var eventDate = $(value).closest('.fc-content-skeleton').find('thead td').eq(eventDateIndex).data('date');
                    if($(value).closest('.fc-content-skeleton').find('thead td.fc-day-number').eq(eventDateIndex).html() == date.getDate()){    
                        if(eventTimeArr.length == 1){   
                            eventTimeArr[0] = eventTimeArr[0].slice(0,-1);
                            eventTimeArr[0] = parseInt(eventTimeArr[0])
                            if(AmPm == 'p'){
                                eventTimeArr[0] = parseInt(eventTimeArr[0])+12;
                            }

                            if( Date.parse(eventDate+' '+eventTimeArr[0]+":"+eventTimeArr[1]) - date.valueOf() <= 900000 ){
                                $('.remainder').append( "<span>"+($(value).find('.fc-title').text())+"</span>, ");
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            eventTimeArr[1] = eventTimeArr[1].slice(0,-1);
                            eventTimeArr[0] = parseInt(eventTimeArr[0])
                            if(AmPm == 'p'){
                                eventTimeArr[0] = parseInt(eventTimeArr[0])+12;
                            }
                            eventTimeArr[1] = parseInt(eventTimeArr[1]);

                            if( Date.parse(eventDate+' '+eventTimeArr[0]+":"+eventTimeArr[1]) - date.valueOf() <= 900000 ){
                               $('.remainder').append( "<span>"+($(value).find('.fc-title').text())+"</span>, ");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                  }
                });    
            }

        }, 1000);
```

And my html ,

```
Remainder : The following task comes up in 15 mins ---- <label class="remainder"></label>
```

I tried to debug it using console.log and found that my code got stuck whenever it executes .fc-* (.fc-center,.fc-day-grid-event,.fc-time)

Can anyone help me to come out of this . And  please let me know ,if you have any other solution to implement remainder functionality .

Comment: it will be easy and better if you provide working demo on fiddle or other tool.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are fetching events from a database, I don't think I'd bother with fullCalendar at all in this solution. If the user is logged in to my site, every minute or so I would query the database through an ajax call for any events belonging to the user that starts in the next X minutes and then create a notification if any are returned.